# Not centered title page

Tags: titles

I'm using this template of title page for my book from [here](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf) named TMB. However, it is not centered, just like the default title page using \maketitle.  Is there any way I can center my title page?

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt,twoside]{book}


\newcommand*{\titleTMB}{\begingroup% Three Men in a Boat
\newlength{\drop}
\setlength{\drop}{0.1\textheight}
\centering
\settowidth{\unitlength}{\LARGE THE BOOK OF CONUNDRUMS}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
{\large\scshape Many names}\\[\baselineskip]
\rule{\unitlength}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
\rule{\unitlength}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
{\LARGE My book's title}\\[\baselineskip]

\rule{\unitlength}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
\rule{\unitlength}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]

\vfill

{\small\scshape 11 March 2014}\par
\vspace*{\drop}
\endgroup}


\begin{document}


\begin{titlepage}
\titleTMB
\end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are using `twoside` so the pages will not be centred by default. You could use e.g. `geometry` to change this while keeping the double-sided layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, when a book is to be printed double-sided, the pages are not centred. Instead, a larger margin is allowed on the outer edges so that when looking at a double-page spread, the white space is evenly distributed.

However, if you do not want this, you can keep the double-sided features while centring pages:

[image: Centred titlepage]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}% note: a4paper - not a4
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}% equal left and right margins

\newcommand*{\titleTMB}{\begingroup% Three Men in a Boat
\newlength{\drop}
\setlength{\drop}{0.1\textheight}
\centering
\settowidth{\unitlength}{\LARGE THE BOOK OF CONUNDRUMS}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
{\large\scshape Many names}\\[\baselineskip]
\rule{\unitlength}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
\rule{\unitlength}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
{\LARGE My book's title}\\[\baselineskip]

\rule{\unitlength}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
\rule{\unitlength}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]

\vfill

{\small\scshape 11 March 2014}\par
\vspace*{\drop}
\endgroup}


\begin{document}


\begin{titlepage}
\titleTMB
\end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

The title page is not intended to be the *cover*. It is, rather the title page which is placed *inside* the book. So the margins should be consistent with those on other pages. However, if you are making a quasi-book in which the title page will be the cover, you might want only the title page to be centred.

[image: Centred titlepage; default margin ratio for body]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcommand*{\titleTMB}{\begingroup% Three Men in a Boat
\newlength{\drop}
\setlength{\drop}{0.1\textheight}
\centering
\settowidth{\unitlength}{\LARGE THE BOOK OF CONUNDRUMS}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
{\large\scshape Many names}\\[\baselineskip]
\rule{\unitlength}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
\rule{\unitlength}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
{\LARGE My book's title}\\[\baselineskip]

\rule{\unitlength}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
\rule{\unitlength}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]

\vfill

{\small\scshape 11 March 2014}\par
\vspace*{\drop}
\endgroup}


\begin{document}


\begin{titlepage}
\titleTMB
\end{titlepage}

\newgeometry{hmarginratio=2:3}

\kant[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! And yes, I only want the title page to be centered and the cover.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that Harish Kumar's solution and mine are (I think) equivalent in that setting the `hmarginratio` to `1:1` centres the page and setting it to `2:3` reinstates the defaults. If you have two pages you want centred at the start, just make sure the `\newgeometry` comes after the second one.

Answer (score 7):

As noted by cfr, since you are using `twoside` option, there is always space left on the inner edge (meant for binding). Hence your pages are not centered. You can use the package geometry, and center only the title page by

```
\newgeometry{centering}    %%% make the page centered on paper
\begin{titlepage}
\titleTMB
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry      %% restore the page layout as earlier
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\newcommand*{\titleTMB}{\begingroup% Three Men in a Boat
\newlength{\drop}
\setlength{\drop}{0.1\textheight}
\centering
\settowidth{\unitlength}{\LARGE THE BOOK OF CONUNDRUMS}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
{\large\scshape Many names}\\[\baselineskip]
\rule{\unitlength}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
\rule{\unitlength}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
{\LARGE My book's title}\\[\baselineskip]

\rule{\unitlength}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
\rule{\unitlength}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]

\vfill

{\small\scshape 11 March 2014}\par
\vspace*{\drop}
\endgroup}


\begin{document}

\newgeometry{centering}
\begin{titlepage}
\titleTMB
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I like the \newgeometry{centering}. It works wonderful.